# Polymer hostAttributes Error

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I have been following along the Polymer 1.0 Developer guide and I stumbled when getting up to the [specific part about hostAttributes](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#host-attributes).

When I take the example code from the docs:

```
hostAttributes: {
  string-attribute: 'Value',
  boolean-attribute: true
  tabindex: 0
}
```

and add it to my prototype, the browser keeps throwing the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
```

on the lines where there are dashes. Strangely, when I put quotes around `string-attribute` and `boolean-attribute`, it renders fine.

Is this an error on my part or is it an error in the docs somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In The way that this example represented `string-attribute`, `string-attribute` refers to a string as an attribute that should be set on the label of your element declaration. Also, as you may have noticed by the way you are declaring `string-attribute` in the example, Javascript assumes that `string-attribute` is a variable, and variables can not be declared as "my-variable" are declared "myvariable", all strings together.
I think that's the reason why you should declared as follows:

```
hostAttributes: {
  "my-var": 'Value',// Javascript assumes that my-bar is an string
  my-var-two: 'value'// Javascript assumes that my-bar-two is a variable (this will fail)
  tabindex: 0
}
```

I hope you have understood me, my English is very bad.

### Edit

> If a custom elements needs HTML attributes set on it at create-time, these may be declared in a hostAttributes property on the prototype, **where keys are the attribute name and values are the values to be assigned. Values should typically be provided as strings, as HTML attributes can only be strings;**

```
hostAttributes: {
  string-attribute: 'Value', //string-attribute is a key, should be inside "" because javascript's keys doesn't accepts "-"
  boolean-attribute: true//will fail because is not a key
  tabindex: 0//this works because for javascript this is a correct key
}
```

> ...however, **the standard serialize method is used to convert values to
> strings**, so true will serialize to an empty attribute, and false will
> result in no attribute set, and so forth

As you can realize, only serialized string values, never mentioned that the keys are serialized as string as well. As I mentioned before, my English is bad and I understood that.

Comment: thank you for your answer and I understand how variable names work, but I am referring specifically to Polymer syntax where in the documentation it states that you can plainly list hostAttributes as non-strings and it will parse it into attribute names and values.

Comment: @simplexity I hope this explanation will help you a little more.